# Putty ssh commands zip all the files within this folder then download

Tags: ssh, directory, command, zip, putty

oh so i cd into my folder

```
ls
cgi-bin                      wp-comments-post.php  wp-mail.php
googlec3erferfer228fc075b.html  wp-commentsrss2.php   wp-pass.php
index.php                    wp-config-sample.php  wp-rdf.php
license.txt                  wp-config.php         wp-register.php
php.ini                      wp-content            wp-rss.php
readme.html                  wp-cron.php           wp-rss2.php
wp-activate.php              wp-feed.php           wp-settings.php
wp-admin                     wp-includes           wp-signup.php
wp-app.php                   wp-links-opml.php     wp-trackback.php
wp-atom.php                  wp-load.php           xmlrpc.php
wp-blog-header.php           wp-login.php
(uiserver):u45567318:~/wsb454434801 >
```

What i want to do is zip all the files within this folder then download it to my computer i am really new to ssh and this is a clients website but really want to start to use command line for speed, i have been looking a this reference http://ss64.com/bash/ to find the right commands but would really like some help from somebody please??

Thanks

Comment: did you found the command?

Comment: why not just use rsync? it will copy the files via ssh, and retain the folder structure, and is available on all *nix systems.

Answer (score 37):

```
cd path/to/folder/foldername
zip -r foldername.zip foldername *    [use * if it has any sub directory]
```

Please try this code, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 22):

If you are in  directory itself then

```
zip -r zipfilename.zip  *
```

Answer (score 17):

Go to folder path using cd command

```
zip -r foldername.zip foldername
```

Ex : zip -r test-bkupname.zip test

Here test is the folder name.

Answer (score 2):

```
tar zcvf ../my_directory.tar.gz .
```

will create my_directory.tar.gz file.

```
scp ../my_directory.tar.gz username@your-ip:/path/to/place/file
```

will transfer file to your computer.

Comment: hi im having some issues it wont download to desktop here is the code im using  scp ../wsb454436346.tar.gz sam@81.109.134.23:c:\docume~1\sam\desktop but it wont work any help please

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is the webroot directory.

Why not zip the directory above (httpdocs / html / whatever) and then move this into the website space, and download from there?

i.e. go into the directory above the web root. For example, if your web root is /var/www/html/ go into /var/www/ and run the following commands:

```
zip -r allwebfiles.zip html
mv allwebfiles.zip /html/allwebfiles.zip
```

Then in your web browser go to http://mydomain.com/allwebfiles.zip and just download that file.

When extracting, you'd just need to either extract into /var/www/ OR extract into webroot and move all files up one level.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Ssh command to download multiple files at one time

mget ./*

Comment: Not recursive as far as I know. At least not on Windows.